# how postman REST Client raw json data is sent to server in POST, PUT calls?

Tags: java, rest, post, http-headers, http-post

I'm working on a application to test API calls, in which i'm able to generate URL for paramaters which is declared with annotation **@Requestparam** and **@Pathvariable**.

But when using **@RequestBody** we use **raw** in post man. I'm not sure how data is sent in raw. I just want to know how to **send data in raw** to server.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

I'm doing this as AJAX using Jquery.

Answer (score 24):

In the **header** option of the request, add `Content-Type:application/json`
[image: header content-type postman json]

and in the **body**, select **Raw** format and put your json params like `{'guid':'61791957-81A3-4264-8F32-49BCFB4544D8'}`

[image: body postman json]

I've found the solution on http://www.iminfo.in/post/post-json-postman-rest-client-chrome

Answer (score 13):

Your Request body should be like below when you use raw:

```
{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2","param3":"value3","param4":"value4"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a double quote for variable and separate it with comma.

## example :

{
"id" :"1",
"name":"xyz"
}

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the 'data' attribute in the $.ajax call as shown here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: Tried using like wise, yet the call was unsuccessful (POST)
$.ajax ({
type:'POST',
   url:'www.mydomain.com/rest/api/post?sessionToken=49998494-9498-556',
   cache: true,
   dataType:'jsonp',
   data: json_data,
   success:function(data){
     $('.api_result').empty(); 
     $('.api_result').append(data); 
 }       
    });

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the below comments, make sure the formatting is right as well.

```html
{
 "param1" : "value1",
 "param2": "value2"
}
```